# How can I display images in Django after uploading?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a small blog. And I will be creating a cover image uploading system.

But after uploading, I'm unable to retrieve the image.

Do you have any solutions?

Here's my model.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_images = models.ImageField(default="media/noimg-l.jpg")
```

and here's form.py:

```
class Createcontent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            "title",
            "content",
            "slug",
            "content_images",
            "status",
        )
        file = forms.FileField()
        widgets = {
            "content": SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

and this is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="row">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and my setting.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'  # Show summernote with Bootstrap4
```

and my views.py

```
ef create_post(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Createcontent(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', post.slug)
else:
    form = Createcontent()
return render(request, 'blog/post_creator.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: In settings.py have you properly configured the MEDIA parameters. It's where upload files are uploaded to. You have also a better field to handle images, check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#imagefield

Comment: and my setting.py

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'  # Show summernote with Bootstrap4

Comment: In the admin area can you see the content_images with the image you uploaded?

Comment: Yeah in the admin area I can upload. but in the form area, I can't upload images

Comment: Weird, I also use crispy forms and never had that behaviour, did you check the POST request on the Network tab of the developer tools of your browser when you submit the form?

Comment: Ok, now I can fix it. 

form = Createcontent(request.POST, request.FILES)